# What happens when the arena timer runs out?

Tags: star-wars-galaxy-of-heroes

I've noticed all my battles in the PvP arena have this 5 minute timer sitting menacingly in the center top.

This seems like an easily testable question, but I was unable to find anyone who had, and I'm unwilling to spend one of my so-heavily-limited arena attempts sciencing this.

What happens when the timer runs out?

Comment: Death Star started firing randomly.
any who died won't get revived.

Comment: This is easy to test.  Put 2 equally matched Phoenix teams together and they will usually fight to a draw

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Nothing too exciting — the match ends in a draw.